# R package versioned dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, versioning, package

I'm updating an R package and have two specific dependencies

```
httr (>= 0.6.1),
jsonlite (>= 0.9.14)
```

If these are not met the package will not function. I can see that if I put them both in Depends these version restrictions will be enforced by R. If I put them under Imports it appears they are not. There is no need for the packages to be put in Depends, I do not need them attached, and I know it is bad practice to do so.

Is it expected that Imports does not enforce version restrictions? Would it be kosher to leave the packages in Imports and have the .onLoad function check for out of date dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) section 1.1.3 says

> The ‘Imports’ field ... Version requirements
>   can be specified and are checked when the namespace is loaded (since R >= 3.0.0).

So it sounds like the lack of version checking is a bug and should be reported to the R-devel [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) or [bug tracker](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/).

Hmm, I think the check is enforced when the namespace is loaded, e.g., `import(httr)` in the NAMESPACE file. If your code were to use `httr::foo()` without ever explicitly importing from httr, then there would be no check, or perhaps a check at run time. So again it seems like a bug, even if consistent with the documentation ('checked when the namespace is *loaded*').

Comment: This seems to be exactly the case. I was using httr:: and jsonlite:: throughout, so the namespace was never loaded. Adding import or importFrom to the NAMESPACE file causes a check to occur. Thank you!